# I want add two numbers and display the total - removing the comma breaks the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to times two numbers together and display at the end of a table.

The code worked until I try to remove commas. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function calc() {
        var $no1 = ($.trim($('.no1').val()) != '' && !isNaN($('.no1').val())) ? parseFloat($('.no1').val()) : 0;

        var $no1 = ($('no1.').val()).replace(/,/g, '');

        console.log($no1);

        var $price1 = $(.trim($('.price1').val()) != '' && !isNaN($('.price1').val())) ? parseFloat($('.price1').val()) : 0;
        var $price1 = ($('.price1.').val()).replace(/,/g, '');

        console.log($price1);
        var n = $no1 * $price1;
        $('.sum1').val(n.toFixed(2));
    }

    $('.key1').keyup(function () {
        calc();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
var No1 = $.trim($('.no1').val()).replace(/,/g, '');
var $no1 = No1  != '' && !isNaN(parseFloat(No1)) ? parseFloat(No1) : 0;

var Price1 = $.trim($('.price1').val().replace(/,/g, '');
var $price1 = Price1 != '' && !isNaN(parseFloat(Price1)) ? parseFloat(Price1) : 0;
```

instead of

```
var $no1 = ($.trim($('.no1').val()) != '' && !isNaN($('.no1').val())) ? parseFloat($('.no1').val()) : 0;
var $no1 = ($('no1.').val()).replace(/,/g, '');
//
var $price1 = $(.trim($('.price1').val()) != '' && !isNaN($('.price1').val())) ? parseFloat($('.price1').val()) : 0;
var $price1 = ($('.price1.').val()).replace(/,/g, '');
```

The error is because **You are assigning the same variable which has the float parsed value with a comma replaced string**.

So, the value in $no1 and $price1 will be strings. after the comma replace.

This code replaces the commas in the first expression itself, before the Float Parsing. so, the $no1 and $price1 are float.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It removes the error, but it doesn't remove the comma. The end sum still comes out as zero. Thank you for your help

Comment: would you give an example of how the textbox value looks?

Comment: ($price1 = 88,000) * ($no1 = 1,000) the function returns 0

Comment: i'm sorry, there is a little error! we check for `IsNaN($('.no1').val())` in the ternary function..! he is true! and the condition is false, returns 0! Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Works great now! Thank you!! A ) is missing after the val() in the Var $price1.

Answer (score 0):

After making replace you need to parse as float again!

Replace creates a string, as you can see here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp